# Setting value for labels, that are coming from database in ExTJS

Tags: forms, label, extjs3

I'm working on a project which is already written with ExtJS and PHP. There is an ExtJS form, which appears when you click on 'edit' button and it has editable text fields such as name, lastname, etc.

It's getting the default values of fields from the database and after submit, it returns them to the database as well, while the name of the column id db is in front of 'name', ex:

```
    firstnameFieldConfig : {
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
        name: db_firstname', //it's a column in db
        allowBlank:false
   },
```

The problem is, I have some values that must be shown on the form, but they are not editable OR they must not be sent to db, they're just some labels like, stundet number which is always fixed. What is the solution? How can I have something fixed in form which it's value is indeed coming from db. but at the end wont be sent anywhere?

P.S: I can use labels (xtype: label) but the problem is label values are fixed and should be hard coded in program.

P.P.S: Application is in ExtJS 3.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use textfields or numberfields and set their disabled property to true.